# I am having problem in starting android studio?

Tags: android, flutter, nosuchmethoderror, android-studio-4.1

[image: Android Studio start fails]

Can Anyone tell the solution of this error . Recently I have updated android studio 4.1 . Then I updated flutter from plugins in android. Then This error is coming . Kindly help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to invalidate cache and restart from the android studio by going, File > Invalidate cache / Restart...
This helped me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

can you try manually updating it using flutter sdk ..
the code is

```
  git pull --rebase
```

apparently this happens commonly when you update versions of the libraries

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove plugins that don't support this newer android studio 4.1 ,

find plugins location here :

```
C:\Users\<your_pc_user_name>\.AndroidStudio4.0\config\plugins
```

and cut paste plugins from here to any other folder (as a backup) , restart android studio and re-download them 1 by 1 if they support android studio 4.1